# Найти корень уравнения на интервале

Tags: c++

Начал изучать C++ недавно и навыки пока не очень большие, помогите пожалуйста с задачей, ни как ни дойдет как ее решить:

> Найти корень уравнения y=ax^2sinx+b при условии, что корень
>   единственный и находится на интервале [x1, x2]. Для нахождения
>   воспользоваться методом деления отрезка пополам. Точность вычисления
>   задается величиной ε>0 которая определяет длину интервала, содержащего
>   корень.

Comment: Вам обязательно нужно ознакомиться с частью стандартной библиотеки math

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 5):

Смотрите - у нас есть уравнение `y(x) = 0`. Надо определить эту функцию

```
double y(double x)
{
    // Тело напишите сами
}
```

У нас отрезок, на котором ищем. Так? Значит, есть

```
double a,b;
```

(не забудьте проинициализировать!). Далее, нам надо знать знаки значений функции в этих точках:

```
double ya = y(a), yb = y(b);
```

Неплохо бы проверить, что они имеют разные знаки...

Далее будем работать в цикле, сужая отрезок. Т.е. пока не получим `|a-b| < eps`, или, поскольку у нас всегда `b > a`, просто `b-a < eps`. Т.е.

```
while(b - a > eps)
{
```

И что тут? Дели пополам:

```
double x = (a + b)/2;
```

и находим значение функции:

```
double f = y(x);
```

Теперь посмотрим... если оно того же знака, что и `a` - двигаем `a`, если `b` - соответственно.

```
if (ya * f >= 0)  
    a = x;
else
    b = x;
```

На этом цикл заканчивается...

А теперь соберите все это в кучу, допишите, чего не хватает, добейтесь, чтоб компилировалось, отладьте (я мог и ошибку где пропустить... :)) и несите сдавать.

P.S. Вы же не надеялись всерьез получить готовую работу? :)

Comment: Спасибо большое, нет конечно, этого вполне достаточно чтобы понять куда двигаться и как должен работать код